# How do I solve error in installing Minikube for Kuberntes on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization

I am trying to install minubuke locally for Kubernetes. I tried to confirm virtualization on my Linux PC using this `sudo grep -E --color 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo` and I got this error:

```
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
```

I tried to sort the issue by running `sudo apt-get update` and I got this error below:

```
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ozmartian/apps/ubuntu focal Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:23 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_NG) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ozmartian/apps/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_NG) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:2
```

I really do not know what to do, please could anyone help, I'd appreciate a lot. Thanks.

Comment: `I tried to confirm virtualization .... and I got this error` What you show is not an error: is the output from `grep` command, confirming your CPU is able to use `vmx` with virtual machines.

Comment: `I tried to sort the issue by running sudo apt-get update and I got this error below` It looks like your APT `sources` has some issues. Look into `/etc/apt/sources*` and fix the errors (probably, none of them related to Kubernetes).

Comment: @emi  the grep output is flagging red on my terminal and I am following the minikube docks here https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

Comment: `grep output is flagging red on my terminal` this is because you used `grep --color`, not because it is an error. Look into the results: both lines contain the string `vmx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to check if processor supports Virtualization Technology.

You should look in the `flags` section in the `/proc/cpuinfo` file for one of two possible values: **vmx** (intel) or **svm** (amd).

Instead of manually checking this file, you can use the `grep` command as in your case:

```
$ sudo grep -E --color 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo
```

In your output you can find **vmx** (Intel-VT technology):

```
flags       : ... vmx ...
```

This means that your CPU supports virtualization technology.

#### Fixing a 404 Error when updating package lists.

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ozmartian/apps/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
```

The error above is telling you that this repository is not available for your current Ubuntu version.
You can find detailed explanation and possible workaround in this [article](https://itsfoss.com/repository-does-not-have-release-file-error-ubuntu/). Additionally, there is a similar [problem with accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034146/how-do-i-fix-404-error-when-updating-package-lists).

In short, you can just remove this repository with:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -r http://ppa.launchpad.net/ozmartian/apps/ubuntu
```

And then update the package lists:

```
$ sudo apt update
```